# How to reduce the latency in case of Indexing files using Lucene.net

Tags: lucene.net

Hi We are planning to use lucene.net as apart of one of our products which is mainly a content repository. In order to have better performance, our system will be using a Lucene query engine for majority of content read operation. But one of the major set back that we feel is the latency, as we are unaware of clustered or distributed Lucene Implementation, which is the best method to reduce the latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments I now understand that the latency concerns relate to IP packet latency of having a single index server that is on the other side of the planet from the user.

Lucene.net, like Lucene, is a library not a platform.  It provides blazingly fast indexing and querying, but does not provide higher level platform features like a multi-server distributed index.  Lucene does contain alot of plumbing to support such use cases and it's this plumbing that software products can build on top of to provide multi-server distributed indexes.  The two most popular software platforms built on Lucene that provide such features  are [Apache Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/).  It's important to note however that they are built on top of the Java version of Lucene rather than Lucene.net.  I am not aware similar alternatives for Lucene.net, and building your own would be a major undertaking.

It is possible however that the IP packet latency you are concerned about may not turn out to be a large issue, let me explain.  It's often possible to send an IP request to the other side of the planet in under 300ms, certainly under 500ms.  When rendering a web page served from the other side of the planet with lots of images served from there as well, this latency can add up quickly.  At 300ms per image if the page had 20 images on it plus a few css files and a few js files all loaded from that server, then rendering the page could require say 25 requests.  At 300ms latency per request, such a situation would bear 7500ms in latency, or 7.5 secs.  In reality some of the requests could be served in parallel, which would reduce the effective latency, but on top of this latency the sever has to do work to meet the request and that takes time too.  Anyway, this example is just for illustration purposes to agree that serving a web page from the other side of the world does raise IP latency concerns.

**However,** making a search request from Lucene from the other side of the planet does not have similar issues because it need only be a single request.  So for example, if a person needs to issue a search to a API server on the other side of the planet running Lucene.net, the request (probably json) is a single request that bares the IP latency, say 300ms.  That request is serviced by Lucene.net and the results are returned as a single response to that request and then the App or web page that made the request renders the results.  So the total IP latency is just the IP latency of a single request which for many use cases would be fine done across the globe.

Comment: We are developing a SAAS platform where the contents are indexed with an indexing engine (Lucene), As our stak is completely in microsoft tech, we decided to use lucene.net (There are some other use cases which is the reason for sticking with lucene) but now the issue we assume to be face is the response time for a user located in far away location who query something.

Comment: Are you saying you are concerned about IP packet latency    of having a single index server that is on the other side of the planet from the user?  Is that the concern? If so it’s best to update the question to add clarification.

Comment: Yeah exactly. that was what my concern is to be precise

Comment: Finally i saw something related to Lucene.net which can have a distributed network with nCache.